# android soft keyboard modifications

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is there a way to programmatically remove certain keys from the standard software keyboard. By setting some of the input type flags I am so close to having the keyboard I need. From the calling application is there a way to modify the keyboard directly. I know how to make my own custom keyboard but it seems such a waste to remove one button from the standard one.

////// edit/////// 
I think I found a way around this if any one has tried this method please let me know if it worked for you.

I have going to grab the softKeyboard service and using the start hook the keyboard uses to grab its view object inflate my own and swap them.

Comment: Not what you want, but could you just make it ignore or error beep/toast on the illegal key and thus train the user not to push it?

Comment: I doubt you watch the show House but if you do that comment is extra funny. I was think that to stop end users from trying to lick my interface I could cover their screens in hot sauce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my research there is no way to implement your own custom keyboard from within a single application. If you want to have a custom keyboard you need to create one from scratch and can not use the IME

Comment: Have a look at Soft Keyboard sample (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html). You can make keyboard look whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

soft keyboard comes for edit text. you can modify the softkeyboard for that edit text.
    For that you need to set inputType and imeOption property of that edit text.

Comment: There is no combination of options that produce the appropriate keyboard, that would be to easy. Is there a way I can grab the service and inflate my custom keyboard. I am not changing any functionality just setting the keys I would like to appear. Nothing about the keyboard I want is non standard.  It seems like so much extra to create a keyboard service when I only need to modify a single key!

Comment: android:imeOptions="actionSend" - this way you can change the name of enter button. There are many other options to do so. Try it. You can also change the keyboard type ie input type. try android:inputType="text". There are also many other option. These way you can choose various soft keyboard. But in case of total custom keyboard, i dont think you can do that.